# How to only update Role not the permission through Rally Node RestApi

Tags: node.js, api, rest, rally, user-permissions

How do I only update the Role but not the Project Permission for a user for a particular project? Below code would update not just the Role but  the Project Permission as well.

```
//Get TeamMembers for the project

restApi.query({ 
            ref: projectRef + '/TeamMembers',
            limit: Infinity, 
            fetch:['UserName', 'ObjectID', 'Role'],
            scope: { workspace: workspaceRef }
        })
//updating the Role of the Team Member


   restApi.update({ 
            ref: /user/userOID,
            data: {Role:RoleName},
            fetch:['UserName', 'ObjectID', 'Role'],
            scope: { workspace: workspaceRef }
        })
```

[image]

Comment: What you have above should work.  Are you getting an error?  What do you mean it's updating the Project Permission as well?

Comment: If I update someone to be a developer it will update the role as Developer and  the project permission is set to Editor. The above code does that.

 I dont want to set the person's project permission to be Editor but just set the Role to be Developer.

Comment: I found the issue, some other function was overriding it :-)
Thank you!